# How to implement an ArrayList into an ArrayList to simulate a 2D arrays?

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'm quite new to Javascript, and could use some help trying to understand how to implement an ArrayList into an ArrayList.

I need to add data from a 2 columns x 3 rows table, where as column one has a string variable and column 2 has an integer variable.

What I've done so far :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
array_list.add("Fred" + 11);
array_list.add("Tom" + 21);
array_list.add("Bob" + 31);
```

I want the '+ 11' to belong to a different arraylist, and be displayed like:

Fred 11
Tom 21
Bob 31

Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: I suppose that you are talking about "Java" not "Javascript", right ?

Answer (score 0):

The best practices says you should implement your own class holding name and the number. If you do so one arraylist will suffice. You can also overload toString() method of YourClass to format the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list2D = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list1D = new ArrayList<>();
list1D.add("Fred " + 11);
list1D.add("Tom " + 21);
list1D.add("Bob " + 31);
list2D.add(list1D);

list1D = new ArrayList<>();
list1D.add("Fred " + 12);
list1D.add("Tom " + 22);
list1D.add("Bob " + 32);
list2D.add(list1D);

System.out.println(list2D);
```

The output for that code is:

```
[[Fred 11, Tom 21, Bob 31], [Fred 12, Tom 22, Bob 32]]
```